# Problems installing Spotify on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, installation, osx-lion

I just signed up for Spotify and was in the process of installing the client on all of my computers.  I got it working on Windows, my iPod, and even on Linux.  However when I downloaded the client for Mac I have problems.  I downloaded the dmg which mounts fine, but when I try to drag the program to my applications folder I get the following message:

> The operation can't be completed because an unexpected error occurred
>   (error code -8003).

I tried running the application from within the dmg and it works fine.  It's only when I try to copy it somewhere outside of the dmg that I get the error.  For this reason I'm pretty sure its a Mac OS X problem, but I still don't know how to fix it.

Any ideas what could be causing this?  Is it a Mac problem or a Spotify problem?

Comment: This could be a general issue. Can you install other applications by dragging? This error usually comes up when trying to empty trash.

Comment: I can empty my trash just fine. When I googled the error code I saw that most people couldn't empty the trash. So I tried emptying mine and it worked fine.  I had no problem downloading and installing vlc from the dmg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a repair disk permissions and redownloaded the dmg and it installed fine.  I'm not exactly sure what caused the initial problem, but I do know that doing those two things fixed it.